# Difference between ui-sref and $state.go in AngularJS UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there any functional difference between `ui-sref` and `$state.go()`?

`ui-sref` is used in `<a>...</a>` and `$state.go('someState')` is used in a controller.

In HTML, I would use:

```
<a ui-sref="currentState.state1">Link</a>
```

whereas in a function I would use something like:

```
if(someCondition) {
    $state.go('currentState.state1');
}
```

So, is that it or do I need to add something after `$state.go()`? Assuming current state is `currentState`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is no ***functional*** difference between `ui-sref` and `$state.go`. See the doc

#### [Activating a state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state)

> There are three main ways to activate a state:
>
> - Call `$state.go()`. High-level convenience method.
> - Click a link containing the `ui-sref` directive.
> - Navigate to the `url` associated with the state.

So, these are at the end doing the same, and as we can see in the code of the [`ui-sref` directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/b973dad155ad09a7975e1476bd096f7b2c758eeb/src/stateDirectives.js#128):

```
...
element.bind("click", function(e) {
    var button = e.which || e.button;
    if ( !(button > 1 || e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey || e.shiftKey || element.attr('target')) ) {

      var transition = $timeout(function() {
        // HERE we call $state.go inside of ui-sref
        $state.go(ref.state, params, options);
      });
```

it does call **`$state.go()`**

*And also as discussed here: [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref):*

> *`ui-sref='stateName'` - Navigate to state, no params. 'stateName' can be any valid absolute or relative state, following the same syntax rules as `$state.go()`*

Comment: As far as I understand, there is a difference: navigation to the `url` will call the `$urlRouterProvider` matchers, while the two other methods won't.

Comment: Using the ui-sref directive inside an anchor tag will cause the browser to display the target url in the status bar so it's preferable to just handling an ng-click event in the controller because there is more user feedback.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a difference. As you can see in the question:

[Ionic framework $state.go('app.home'); is adding back button on page where i want to go (how to remove it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930702/ionic-framework-state-goapp-home-is-adding-back-button-on-page-where-i-wan)

the $state.go by default adds a back button. The solution to make it behave exactly the same way is to call:

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({disableBack: true});
```

before calling $state.go.