# Ionic framework $state.go('app.home'); is adding back button on page where I want to go (how to remove it)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have app with sidebar menu. I am on second page and I am calling controller function which redirect me to first page using:

```
$state.go('app.home');
```

Problem is that on this page is now displayed back button next sidebar menu icon, see image below:

[image]

Could somebody tell me how to deny to add back button into pages which has assigned sidebar menu?

Thanks for any help.

**app.js is with router config is following:**

```
angular.module('Test', ['ionic', 'config', 'Test', 'LocalStorageModule'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {
   localStorageServiceProvider
     .setPrefix('max_relax');
   $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.saved', {
      url: '/saved',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: 'templates/saved.html',
          controller: 'SavedCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
          controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
        }
      }
    });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

**Edit:**

**Added menu template:**

```
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/home">
          Home
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/saved">
          Saved
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/settings">
          Settings
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: Can you provide us the HTML code of the link for 'app.home' page?

Comment: There is no link, redirect is done using go method. 

I just added menu template.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Use [`$ionicHistory`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/) in your controller before calling `$state.go('app.home')`.

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope,...,$ionicHistory) {
  ...
  $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
    disableBack: true
  });

  $state.go('app.home');
});
```

Comment: $ionicViewService is now deprecated, we have to use $ionicHistory instead. Everything else remains the same.

Comment: when using $state.go, we could just reset the state history, so the framework does not add the back button. This is ideal when going from a login view to the home view:                                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                      historyRoot: true
                  })
 $state.go("app.home");

Answer (score 27):

You can set nextViewOptions before $state.go('Yourstate'). Like
In your controller, you can write,

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
  disableBack: true
});
$state.go('app.home');
```

So for that transition, it will clear the history stack and sets next view as root of the history stack.

Answer (score 4):

At controller which you want to return `HomeCtrl`:

```
.controller('SavedCtrl', function($scope,...,$ionicHistory) {
  ...
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
       disableBack: true
    });

  $state.go('app.home');
 })
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope,...,$ionicHistory) {
     $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have `<ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>` included in `<ion-nav-bar>` you will see a back button by default on any view using `app`.

Removing `<ion-nav-back-button>` will remove the back button from all of the views using `app`. You can selectively disable it based on what template your viewing by setting `hide-back-button="true"` on the `<ion-view>` of that template.

So, in your case, removing `<ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>` from `menu.html` will hide the back button on all views using `app`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too when using Ionic's side menu.

In some cases when selecting an option from the side menu the resulting page/view was showing a back button in the navbar, which it shouldn't (because selecting a menu option should reset the history).

The problem was related to using "ng-click" in the menu option, e.g:

`<ion-item menu-close ng-click="showStartPage()" ...>`

with 'showStartPage' being a Controller method which calls $state.go(...).

Solution was to code it like this:

`<ion-item menu-close href="#/startPage" ...>`

When done like this, Ionic is (apparently) able to properly keep track of the navigation history.

(I didn't try it out but probably "ui-sref" instead of "href" would work too)