# How to hide stateProvider url displayed in Address bar using Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

All,

I am using Angular JS 1.3.0 stateProvider URL for URL routing.

During run time whenever state is being redirected to particular URL , it displayed on the Address bar and it exposes the information about Employee id. Like in this image.

[image]

Is it possible to hide those potential information using Angular JS 1.3.0?

Answer (score 4):

The `personId` is displayed in the url, because its defined as URL parameter.

But we can avoid that, by defining it with params notation:

```
.state("peopleDetail", {
    url : "/",
    params : { personId : null },
    ...
}
```

Check the doc:

#### [$stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

> A map which optionally configures parameters declared in the url, or defines additional non-url parameters. For each parameter being configured, add a configuration object keyed to the name of the parameter.
>
> ...
>   Each parameter configuration object may contain the following properties:

- value
- array
- squash -- (see more in that resource)

For similar stuff and some more details, please check:

[Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28248236/1679310)