# How to define optional parameter using UI-Router without trailing slash as well?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I was working on migration of my Angularjs code from ng-router to UI-Router. In my ng-router I have optional parameters however I realized that same easy way to support optional parameter is not supported in ui-router. Following is my routes from my existing ng-router module.

```
//Define routes for view  using ng-router
$routeProvider.
        when('/my-app/home/:userid?', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/partials/home/HomeView.html',
            controller: 'HomeViewController'
        })                   
        .when('/my-app/:productKey/:userid?', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/partials/productpage/ProductPageView.html',
            controller: 'ProductViewController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/my-app/home'});
```

Note: If you see ":userid" parameter is very smoothly implemented here as optional.

I tried following in ui-router however same is not working. I have gone through many post and it was suggested to duplicate the routes. I really don't want to duplicate as it will make code dirty.

```
//Set the default route

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/my-app/home');
//Define routes for view   (Please make sure the most matched pattern is define at top)
$stateProvider
        .state('viewallcards', {
            url: '/my-app/home/:userid',
            templateUrl: '/templates/partials/home/HomeView.html',
            controller: 'HomeViewController'
        })
        .state('productpage', {
            url: '/my-app/:productKey/:userid',
            templateUrl: '/templates/partials/productpage/ProductPageView.html',
            controller: 'ProductViewController'
        });
```

Here /my-app/home/ works however /my-app/home doesn't work. How to make it without trailing slash as well?

Also following post on same issue has surprised to me to know that this is not supported in ui-router. Is it still valid?
Please help.

Comment: I don't think ui-router's parameterized URLs need question marks in the case of an optional parameter.

Comment: it doesn't work with or without ?. If i remove ? then trailing slash doesn't work.

Comment: When I've used ui-router, I've used the curly brace form for the variables. I couldn't get the colon form to work. Maybe try {userid}? instead of :userid?, FWIW.

Comment: Not working for me :-(

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it loading the page at all and not passing the parameters?

Comment: with {} also it behaves same, i.e. it works only with trailing slash.....if i remove trailing slash then it is not able to find the route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZvO7oLRLXY6VBA8NH42?p=preview)

We can use **`params : {}`** object to define the `userid` exactly as we need *(i.e. ready to be omitted)*.

Check more details about `params` here:

#### [Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28248236/1679310)

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('viewallcards', {
      url: '/my-app/home/:userid',
      params: { 
        userid: {squash: true, value: null }, // this will make both links below working:
        //         #/my-app/home
        //         #/my-app/home/
      },
      ...
    })
    .state('productpage', {
      url: '/my-app/:productKey/:userid',
      ...
    })
```

Check it [in action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZvO7oLRLXY6VBA8NH42?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this, I am sure this should work.

Comment: The docs recommendation to set $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false) did NOT work, whereas this did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, UI Router is in "strict mode" - where it differentiates between routes with a trailing slash and without. You can turn this off by disabling this mode:

> How can I have my routes be activated when the url contains either a trailing slash or not?
>
> Set strictMode to false in your config block:
>
> `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)`
>
> For older version of ui-router, add this snippet to your module's config function. It creates a rule on $urlRouterProvider that maps all urls that are missing a trailing slash to the same url but with the trailing slash appended.

Using this, it's best to define your optional parameters as URL parameters in the style of `home?userid=foo`, and set stuff that you always expect to see in the URL.

From the UI-Router's [Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes).

Comment: Which option will be better? Using {squash: true, value: null } or $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)?

Comment: I think for your case, squash: true is better as it better allows you to define an Optional parameter that is part of the URL. I've used strictMode(false) to define that I want the route to contain a trailing slash or not where I've used URL parameters and it's worked really well for me.