# ui-router default stateParam

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state defined as such:

```
.state('dashboard.poor-calls', {
    url: '/voice-quality/{callType}/{categoryTypeId}/{:categoryEntityId}/?{:tableView}',
    template: '<poor-calls></poor-calls>',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

Notice that `categoryEntityId` is optional.

Is there a way to specify a default value for `categoryEntityId` if it's not provided in the `state()` definition, or does the controller of my `<poor-calls>` directive *have to* check for a missing `categoryEntityId` and assume the default value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can use **`params : {}`** configuration property:

```
.state('dashboard.poor-calls', {
    url: '/voice-quality/{callType}/{categoryTypeId}/{:categoryEntityId}/?{:tableView}',
    params: {categoryEntityId: 1}
    template: '<poor-calls></poor-calls>',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

and we can even set what to do if that default value is provided, for example skip it from url *(the squash `setting`)*:

```
params: { 
   categoryEntityId: {
      value: 1,
      squash: false,
   },
},
```

See all the details here:

#### [Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28248236/1679310)

#### [How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25647454/1679310)