# Can get parameters from URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I am working on my angularui project.
In moduleI try to get variable that I sent in URL.

Here is module definition:

```
angular.module("workPlan", ['damageEvent',
                            'ui.router',
                            'geomindCommon',
                            'templates',
                            'lookups',
                            'ngTouch',
                            'ui.grid',
                            'ui.grid.expandable',
                            'ui.grid.selection',
                            'ui.grid.pinning',
                            'ui.grid.resizeColumns',
                            'ui.bootstrap'
])

.config([
    "$stateProvider",
    "$urlRouterProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/MainPage");
        $stateProvider
            .state("workPlan", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/",
                template: "<ui-view></ui-view>"
            })

         .state("workPlan.list", {
             url: "MainPage",
             templateUrl: "app/workPlan/templates/workPlanList.tmpl.html",
             controller: "workPlanListController",
             controllerAs: "list",
             resolve: {
                 param: function ($stateParams) {

                     var stringParam = $stateParams.myParam;
                     return $stateParams.myParam;
                 },
                 filterParameters: [filterParametersResolver],
                 workPlans: ["workPlanServise", workPlanServiseResolver]
             }
         })
    }
]);
```

In this rows I try to get params from URL:

```
param: function ($stateParams) {    
    var stringParam = $stateParams.myParam;
    return $stateParams.myParam;
},
```

Here is my URL:

```
http://example.com/playground#/MainPage?myParam = "Some string"
```

But stringParam is always `undefined`.

Any idea what Ia am doing wrong here? Why `stringParam` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must define parameter. Either in `url` or with `params : {}` object. So this should solve it:

```
.state("workPlan.list", {
     //url: "MainPage",
     url: "MainPage?myParam", // here we say, that myParam is expected in url
```

Other ways how to set `params`

- [Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28248236/1679310)
- [How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25647454/1679310)

Comment: myParam can be optional?

Comment: Your param could be anything - what UI-Router supports. With `params: {}` **(see my links)** you can define it with default values, if it should be squashed, or if it should be named param like ?param1=x&param2=y...