# Pass `params` for embedded view ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I'm using UI-Router to build an application.  I need to have multiple views on one page so I'm using abstract states.  I tried to pass the parameter "isEmbedded" to the `owner` view, but it's unfortunately not working.  I'm wondering if its because I'm passing it to a child view.  When I `console.log($stateParams)` in `ownerCtrl`, it does not show the `isEmbedded` parameter.  Any idea why?

```
.state('dog', {
    url: "",
    parent: "dogAbstract",
    views: {
        "owner": {
            templateUrl: 'client/people/views/owner.ng.html',
            controller: 'ownerCtrl',
            params:{
                isEmbedded:true
            }
        }
    }
})
```

P.S. I got the idea to use `params` from this question:

[Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248236/angular-ui-router-passing-data-between-states-without-url)

Comment: The `stateParams` belongs to state, not to view. Why you need to have params `isEmbedded`? What purpose that should serve to?

Comment: I need to render the owner view slightly differently if it is embedded.  I render owner view on its own sometimes, and at other times I render it within another view, and I need to know which it is in in order to make required changes.

Comment: I would say, that the best is to use `resolve`. I created an example to demonstrate that. The advantage is, that it could be view (not just state) related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While $stateParams belongs to state, we can use special resolve for a view:

```
...
views: {
    "owner": {
        templateUrl: 'client/people/views/owner.ng.html',
        controller: 'ownerCtrl',
        resolve:{
            isEmbedded: function() { return true},
        }
    }
}
```

I created [an example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H71cODikgKBJmVfsjiSr?p=preview) with these two child states

```
.state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
      resolve: {
        isEmbedded: function() { return false},
      }
})
.state('parent.child2', { 
      url: "/child2",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
      resolve: {
        isEmbedded: function() { return true},
      }
})
```

And controller can consume it:

```
.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', 'isEmbedded', 
  function ($scope, isEmbedded) { 
    console.log(isEmbedded)
  }
])
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H71cODikgKBJmVfsjiSr?p=preview)

Comment: Sweet!  A bit of a workaround, but it is probably the best way given the current state of ui-router.  Probably would have taken me a couple days to learn enough about ui-router to come up with this on my own. Thanks you!

Comment: Great to see that. Enjoy UI-Router ;)

Comment: Hi Radim, I've run into a problem.  If I don't write the `resolve` code on every state that contains `owner` I get `Unknown provider isEmbedded` error.  Any way to solve this without writing the `resolve` on every state that contains owner?

Comment: Yes. There is - see this updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/qjinnTwIuQk4Zi7jA9nm?p=preview. The point is - move the default setting to the root state of the state hierarchy. Each state will/could be by default be provided with default setting ... but ones you want could override that. I for example have one state "app" on top of all, exactly for such kind of reason... enjoy this mighty extension - UI-Router ;)