# How to define defaults for query params in AngularJS UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have a route:

```
.state('list', {
  url:'/list?query',
  templateUrl: '/views/list.html',
  controller: 'ListCtrl as vm'
})
```

Is there a way to ensure a default value for the query?

I don't want to do it in the controller, as I use the same controller for other routes, and the controller has certain behaviour if the `query` is undefined.

What I want is this particular route to default that `query`.

In the old angular route I have done this sort of thing...

```
.when('/list', 
  templateUrl: '/views/list.html',
  controller: 'ListCtrl'
  controllerAs:true,
  redirectTo:function(routeParams, path, search) {
    if(!search.query) {
      return "list?query=defaultSearch";   
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a setting called **`params`**. There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IDp6xN7aZD4etTlNBnzO?p=preview)

```
.state('list', {
  url:'/list?query',
  templateUrl: 'views/list.html',
  controller: 'ListCtrl as vm',
  params: { query: 'DEFAULT VALUE' }, // here the default
})
```

and these links will work as expected

```
<a href="#/list?"> - with default 'query' value 
<a href="#/list?query=someParam">
<a ui-sref="list({query:'theParam'})">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IDp6xN7aZD4etTlNBnzO?p=preview)

The details are discussed here:

#### [Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28248236/1679310)

Comment: awesome, this looks like the perfect answer.  To date I've been doing this, which is a bit hacky....     `resolve: {updateParams: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
      if(!$stateParams.query) { $stateParams.query="DEFAULT VALUE"; }
    }]}`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the onEnter method to execute logic before your controller loads.

From the ui-router wiki https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki:

```
$stateProvider.state("contacts", {
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  resolve: { title: 'My Contacts' },
  controller: function($scope, title){
    $scope.title = title;
  },
  onEnter: function($location){
    if($location){ ... do something ... }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you right, you need to go to a state if the user requested state does not match any of the states defined.

If this is the requirement, then try using "otherwise" method of $urlRouterProvider

like,

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/default-state");
```

Comment: I tried this, but it appears that `query` params are optional, so the route matches if it defined or not.