# Angular ui-router : Passing params between states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, parameters

I'm trying to pass a message from state1 to state2 in ui-router.

looked up most of the question on here about this topic but unfortunately can't make sense of it.

This is my main code and $stateProvider :

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "state1.html"
    })
        .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "state2.html"
    })

});
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/t1VzffirJcoh0iJnURVY?p=preview) is a Plunker of what i created to test this out.

What should i do to make it work? Thanks

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248236/angular-ui-router-passing-data-between-states-without-url

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "state1.html"
    })
        .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2/:id",
      templateUrl: "state2.html"
    })

});
```

or

```
 myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      //
      // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
      //
      // Now set up the states
      $stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
          url: "/state1",
          templateUrl: "state1.html"
        })
            .state('state2', {
          url: "/state2",
          templateUrl: "state2.html",
          params: {id: ""}
        })

    });
```

then the ui-serf

```
<a ui-sref="state2({id:'value'})">Send param and go to page 2</a>
```

the name (id) have to be equal