# Conditional Routing in $state.go and call edit method angularjs

Tags: angularjs

We have functionality where in we have make reservation editable,when user clicks on link from email.

Currently user can browse in the website and lookup based on the email address and then click on edit to make changes to reservation,so the edit functionality is like a child only action.

```
<button ng-if="!reservation.editing" test-id="reservations-reservation-edit-button" ng-click="edit(reservation)" class="btn btn-link change-link details-edit-reservation-link">Edit</button>
```

The email link will have parameters like "RId","UserId" ...

The question is how can we invoke the edit action directly, based on the parameter passed. 
Below is the snippet of current $state.go

```
 sp.state('reservations', {
    url: '/reservations?e&getDetail&edit',
    templateUrl: 'src/reservations/template.html',
    data: {
      backState: "back",
      shortTitle: "Reservations"
    }
```

Can we make any changes in $state, so that we can do conditional routing and then invoke the edit 
and edit functionality function snippet looks like this

```
 $scope.edit = function(reservation){
      scrollToTop(true);
       .....}
```

Comment: You want to run that `$scope.edit` function if you have some params in the url?

Comment: @chinni Yes.. and pass the parameter values to that method

Comment: yes you can but not sure is the best idea

Comment: check this question i answered that and its the same
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300146/angular-js-routing-control-with-dynamic-parameter-passing/38301042#38301042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you can solve it using `$stateParams`

Your controller:

```
yourApp.controller("YourCtrl"), function($scope, $stateParams) {
    var edit = $stateParams.edit;
    var getDetail = $stateParams.getDetail;
    var e = $stateParams.e;

    $scope.edit = function (params) {
        ...
    };

    if(edit && e) { // have whatever condition you want for enabling editing
        // run the function and pass the stateParams to the function
        $scope.edit($stateParams);
    }
});
```

Note that `$stateParams` will be a `json` with keys to be the param names and values to be the param values in the url. Please refer the official [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) for more info.

Hope this solves the issue.