# UI Router Params value is coming as undefined in destination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I want to pass the parameter values from one page to another without showing the values in URL. Since I am using ui-router so I come across "params" thing but somehow I could not make it work. Please see the code sample as below:-

**index.html**

```
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/AngularControllers/LoginHomeControllers/RouteMainController.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/AngularControllers/LoginHomeControllers/LoginController.js"></script>
 <script src="../Scripts/AngularControllers/Test2Controller.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/AngularControllers/Test3Controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view="mainview"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**RouteMainController.js**

```
var app = angular.module("appHome", ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
        .state('introduction', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'mainview':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Login.html',
                    controller: 'ctrlLogin'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            views: {
                'mainview':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Login.html',
                    controller: 'ctrlLogin'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'mainview':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Home.html',
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home.requestsummary', {
            url: '/requestsummary',
            views: {
                'homedetailview':
                {                    
                    templateUrl: 'Test2.html',    
                    controller: 'ctrlReqSumm'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home.requestsummary.hello', {
            url: '/requestdetail',           
            views: {
                'homedetailview@home':
                {                    
                    template: 'Test3.html',
                    controller: 'ctrlRequestDetail',
                    params: { paramOne: "defaultValueOne" }
                }
            }
        })
});
```

**Login.html**

```
<div>
    <button id="btnAdd" type="submit"  ng-click="Login()">Login</button>
</div>
```

**LoginController.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('appHome');
myApp.controller("ctrlLogin", ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.Login = function () {
        window.location.href = '#!home/requestsummary';       
    }
}]);
```

**Home.html**

```
<!--Sample Code for displaying Menu Tab and corresponding link-->
<li>
    <a href="#">Employees <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
        <li><a ui-sref=".employeeadd">Add Employee Record</a></li>       
    </ul>
</li>

<div ui-view="homedetailview"></div>
```

**Test2.html**

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="request in requestData">
        {{request.name}}
        <a ui-sref=".requestdetail({paramOne:request.Id})">             
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Test2Controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('appHome');
myApp.controller("ctrlReqSumm", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.requestData = [{
        'Id': "1", 'name': "Hello",
        'Id': "2", 'name': "Hi",
        'Id': "3", 'name': "OK"
    }]
}])
```

**Test3.html**

```
<div>
    <label>The id is: </label> {{requestId}}
</div>
```

**Test3Controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('appHome');
myApp.controller("ctrlRequestDetail", ['$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope,  $stateParams) {

    $scope.requestId = $stateParams.paramOne;

}]);
```

So I want to pass the value of paramOne from **Test2.html** to **Test3.html** and display it there. Currently the parameter paramOne is showing value as **"undefined"**

Please let me know how to use params in this scenario or if there is better approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38913489/3635406)
which provides a working example with two type of parameters.

> make sure that your Usage match: `ui-sref='stateName({param: value, param: value})'`

ok.. i prepared [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LHcR7hgBZxIWfqzSh2uj?p=preview) for you :)

- the main issue in your code is the place you define `Params` property, it should be in the root level (same `url` property's level)
- change `template: 'Test3.html',` to be `templateUrl: 'Test3.html',`
- since `home.requestsummary.hello` state in a child of `home.requestsummary` as you define, i think you need to chenage `'homedetailview@home'` into `'test2detailview@home.requestsummary'`, and have `<div ui-view="test2detailview"></div>` in Test2.html

hope this answer you bro :)

Comment: Still getting stateParams as undefined even after changing the stateName to home.requestsyyummary.requestdetail({paramOne:request.Id}) from .requestdetail({paramOne:request.Id}). Do I need to change anything else than this in my code?

Comment: As you suggested moving Params property to root level only resolved my problem.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the param is not resolved yet? What if you try:

```
myApp.controller("ctrlRequestDetail", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$stateParams', ($rootScope, $scope,  $stateParams) => {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => {
        console.log(toParams, fromParams)
    });

}]);
```

*Note the added `$rootScope` dependency*

Comment: The previous answer helped to resolve. Thanks for your help.