# $scope.data not working in other views having the same controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs

**app.js**

I have created multiple views having the same controller named as vendorCtrl, as we know that $scope can be used withing a specific controller, my question is without the help of $rootscope how can i share data between multiple views named as  basic, areas,  identity

```
$stateProvider
        .state('dashboard.vendor.add',{
            views:{
                '@': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/vendor/forms/basic.html',
                    controller : 'vendorCtrl'   
                }
            }
        })


        .state('dashboard.vendor.add.areas',{
            views:{
                '@': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/vendor/forms/areas.html',
                    controller : 'vendorCtrl'   
                }
            }
        })



        .state('dashboard.vendor.add.identity',{
            views:{
                '@': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/vendor/forms/identity.html',
                    controller : 'vendorCtrl'       
                }
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue regarding scope inheritance

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard.vendor.add',{
        views:{
            '@': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/vendor/forms/basic.html',
                controller : 'vendorCtrl'   
            }
        }
    })


    .state('dashboard.vendor.add.areas',{
        views:{
            '@': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/vendor/forms/areas.html',
                controller : 'vendorCtrl'   
            }
        }
    })
```

**controller**

```
function vendorCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.data= 'hello world';
}
```

**areas.html**

`<input type-"text" ng-modal="data"/>
 <label name="name">{{data}}</label>`

**basic.html**

`<label name="name">{{data}}</label>`

> In this situation value of $scope.data would be display in **areas.html** but failed to display value in **basic.html** despite having same controller. 
>   Because scope properties only inherit down the state chain if the views of our states are nested. Inheritance of scope properties has nothing to do with the nesting of our states and everything to do with the nesting of your views.

Comment: thats ok, we need to create a factory but my doubt is why being on the same controller $scope.xyz  giving empty values for other views

Comment: you can use $scope.xyz in different views in same controller

Comment: yes,  we can but the value in other views for $scope.xyz is showing empty unless and untill i used $rootScope

Comment: may be there is wrong in some other part of code, or share your controller code so i ll lookout. Any ways, why you are using same controller for child view.? controller should be different for child view. it is a bad practice to write parent and child in one controller

Comment: im using it cz more data  to be exchange between my parent state to all other child views

Comment: No add controller where you used $scope.? and go through this link https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Yes but this is not the proper way to share data in child views. you have to declare separate controllers for every view and if you want  to use sharing logic then only uise services

Comment: :thanks, i got the issue, its the scope inheritance that is creating problem

Comment: Ok.! if possible then edit my answer accordingly, so it will be right answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, With `ui-router` you can use [the params property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28248244/644669).

On the other hand, you can use a simple (getter/setter ?) [service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21920241/644669) that can hold your data.