# AngularJS: is $location.path('/newLocation') synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to extend an existing AngularJS application. In the old version, the developer upon pressing a form button `Generate report` would display a hidden `div`. Now due to changes in the use-cases it was necessary to put this `div` within a separate view and dynamically switch to it. So I created a new view in the controller `reportDetails.html` and it works fine. The hidden view is not shown at first because it requires some values to be set.

The old version did this from the "Generate report" view:

```
<td class="selection-fields-report">
   <label class="invisible">Dummy</label><br>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="generateReport()" ng-disabled="reportData.notReadyForReport">Generate Report</button>
</td>
```

My new `generateReport()` implementation attempts to switch to the new view "Report details" and set some DOM elements by `id` assuming that they are already available ... but they aren't:

```
$scope.generateReport = function () {
   // ...
   // switch to the report details
   $location.path('/reportDetails');
   // but this 'filterStr' element is not yet available????
   document.getElementById('filterStr').value = "";
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error here filterStr doesn't exist ... but it is in the new view reportDetails.html
```

Do I have to wait for the `$location.path('/reportDetails');` to finish i.e. is it a synchronous or asynchronous call?

Comment: Changing view is quite complicated operation and async for a lot of reasons, like template resolving, resolving promises in state Resolve, etc.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov and then, what would be the correct way to solve this use-case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248236/angular-ui-router-passing-data-between-states-without-url pass initial input value in state param