# ui router 1.0.3 pass data between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, router

How to pass data between two states. i tried this and it is not working. I saw that stateparams are depricated and this is not a duplicate thread. This is for UI router 1.0.3

In the first controller

```
$state.go('state2', {id: $scope.value} );
```

And in second controller

```
$scope.state2value = $state.params.id;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248236/angular-ui-router-passing-data-between-states-without-url)

Comment: This not duplicate..this is a newer version of ui router

Comment: Why don't you want to use newer version? If the 1.0.3 version doesn't provide an option to share data between states, just update your ui-router. Or let me know if it's not a solution for your case

Comment: Actually, 1.0.3 is the latest version and I want to know how to pass data. It will support, they did not deprecate a feature, they have deprecated the method. @CommercialSuicide

Comment: Does injecting $transition$ and using $transition$.params() as outlined in [this migration guide](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#stateparams-deprecation) not work?

Comment: I tried that, but all returns an empty object @Nickel