# Pass data(resolve/data/params?) to template without controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I have a case in one app where I would like to create a route (.state in ui-router) to go to a printable content. I only need to pass a code to the template of the route and then handle this code in my template. I don't need a controller for this. Just the ability to get a value from a resolve? params attributes? data? and inject it in the view. Is this possible in AngularJS 1.6?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248236/angular-ui-router-passing-data-between-states-without-url)