# Angular 1/ui-router - pass interpreted data from state to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, router, angular-routing

I want to pass a data from the `state` to the controller, I would like the `{{ projectName }}` be interpreted at the `state` level (this `state`) and returns its value (string) directly to the controller.

Is there a way to do this by the `resolve` (the code in the `resolve` was only for the test, but we can in fact retrieve the projectName by `ProjectUtilService.getProjectName(project)`) or the `onEnter` method or for example to execute a function at the same level of `data.title` and which return the `projectName` ...?

```
.state({
    name: 'project.detail.edit.headers.overlay.comment',
    url: '/comment',
    data: {
        title: '{{ projectName }}'
    },
    component: 'iadAgentMyIadComment',
    resolve: {
        projectName: (project, ProjectUtilService) => {
            ProjectUtilService.getProjectName(project)
        }
    }
})
```

EDIT :

```
  getProjectName(project) {
    return project.contactName
  }
```

for example if ProjectUtilService.getProductName (project) returns "Richard Stallman" i want i found on my controller `this.$state.current.data.title` which is equal to Richard Stallman

Comment: If you are trying to pass data from one state to another you can use state params..

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40114183/2810683) what you want?

Comment: I would advise against mutating any data on `$state.current.data`.  Instead, add a binding on your component which receives the `projectName` resolve. https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#resolve-bindings