# Insert html into div with angular keeping ui-router ui-sref property working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

Here is my case:

I have a div which needs to get some html injected from a function:

`<div ng-bind-html="myCtrl.getMyLink()"></div>`

in my controller I have:

```
this.getMyLink = function () {
    return '<a ui-sref="app.go.to.state1">my link</a>';
}
```

It works but not at all. All I have at the end in my html is only

```
<a>my link</a>
```

It's a link but the ui-sref redirection is not working.
There is surely something I'm missing.

How can I fix that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526801/difference-between-ui-sref-and-state-go-in-angularjs-ui-router

Comment: @Hearner that link has nothing to do with compiling html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content inside `ng-bind-html` doesn't get compiled by angular, it is intended for static html.

You would need to use your own directive instead and either set a template or do your own compiling with $compile.

Alternatively you might be able to use `ng-include`. There aren't enough details given for your use case to help much more

Answer (score 4):

`ng-bind-html` does not work with `ui-sref` directive. Just use `href="path/to/state1"` instead