# html entities decode and compile

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

My js object contains double quotes so I store data in the form:

`var data = "un &lt;a ui-sref=&quot;app.concept({id:1})&quot;&gt;test link&lt;\/a&gt;"`

which means `<a ui-sref="app.concept({id:1})">test link<\/a>`

how can I decode the html entities and then compile the ui-sref?
Using this https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile only doesn't work.

It prints `<a ui-sref="app.concept({id:1})">test link<\/a>` in the view

Comment: why do you store data like this?

Comment: My data contains this anchor. If I try to escape the double quotes of the ui-sref the result of the directive compiling is: `<a class>test link</a>`. Maybe I miss something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be better/easier to store that data as an actual unescaped html string.  This would require much less work.

However, if you can't do that, then you may want to inject the $sce service into your controller and then use the `data = $sce.trustAsHtml(data)` after your data variable declaration.

After doing this, use `<div ng-bind-html="data"></div>` in the view. It should fix your issue.

If that doesn't completely work, you can try to unescape the data variable using a function in underscore called unescape.  So `trustAsHtml(_.unescape(data))` can help you.

**Router UI addition**

Since you are using router-ui, your best bet is probably to do as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32222774/2236808) and just use `href="path/to/state1"` if possible.

Comment: I have a ui-sref directive in the string, ng-bind-html doesn't compile.

Comment: @alfredopacino I just modified my answer. I think that if you are going this route, then you may just want to do what I suggest and not use ui-sref at all.

Comment: yeah I guess I would use the href solution (we know it's not the best option but it's better than encode the quotes..)