# UI-Router considering url as state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have my routing defined as below

```
$stateProvider
    ('MasterPage', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/master.html',
})
.state('MasterPage.dashboard', {
    url: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'views/dash.html',
})
.state('MasterPage.test', {
    url: 'test/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
})
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

I have links that allows me to navigate from mainpage to dashboard and then to the test page which works fine. When I navigate to the test page with an id:1234, which makes my url as `<HOST>/#/test/1234`, and try to refresh it fails. It gives me an error saying:

> Cannot resolve state 'MasterPage.test/1234' from 'MasterPage.test'

Why is UI-Router considering the url segment as a state?

**Update**
I dont have any ui-sref. I am going to the test page by using `$state.go('MasterPage.test', {id:1234})`.

Answer (score 1):

There is [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rSC2toCi6RMYn6otWMmx?p=preview)

This issue is usually related to wrong `ui-sref` setting

```
<a ui-sref="MasterPage.test/1234">
```

we need to split and pass 1) the state name, and 2) state params like this:

```
<a ui-sref="MasterPage.test({id:1234})">
```

In case, we want to use `href`, we just have to concatenate *parent* and *child* `url` definitions *(parent '/', child 'test/:id')* :

```
<a href="/test/1234">
```

#### EXTEND

So, these states (almost unchanged):

```
    .state('MasterPage', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/master.html',
    })
    .state('MasterPage.dashboard', {
      url: 'dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'views/dash.html',
    })
    .state('MasterPage.test', {
      url: 'test/:id',
      templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
    })
```

will work with these links

```
  <a href="#/">
  <a href="#/dashboard">
  <a href="#/test/1234">
  <a href="#/test/9875">
  <a ui-sref="MasterPage">
  <a ui-sref="MasterPage.dashboard">
  <a ui-sref="MasterPage.test({id:2222})">
  <a ui-sref="MasterPage.test({id:4444})">
```

There is [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rSC2toCi6RMYn6otWMmx?p=preview)

Comment: I dont have any ui-sref. I am going to the test page by using `$state.go('MasterPage.test', {id:1234})`.

Comment: ui-sref and $state.go do have almost the same syntax... (ui-sref behind uses $state.go - http://stackoverflow.com/q/24526801/1679310... so, this must work `$state.go('MasterPage.test', {id:1234})`... I can try to create a plunker...

Comment: I created a plunker for you, showing your state def in action.. and it is working ;)